# ServiceStack MonoTouch client with Basic Auth - JSON Parser and Cookie exceptions

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, xamarin.ios, servicestack

For starters, BasicAuth seems to be properly configured on the service side (the service is a REST service, inheriting from `RestServiceBase`, if that's of any importance here), at least it works perfectly fine when using the browser.

I have two problems here when trying to use the client for the service under MonoTouch (I'm using the `IServiceClient` interface with `JsonServiceClient` backing it up):

1. When I put in wrong credentials, I get the exception saying 'Invalid UserName or Password', which is all fine and peachy. But when I put in ANYTHING for the second time , be it correct or incorrect credentials, and try to send a request I get the `Internal Server Error` exception with the `ReponseDto` containing:

   `Error Code: Cookie Exception, Message: The 'Name' = '$Version' part of the cookie is invalid`

   I'm using the `SetCredentials` method, the `AlwaysSendBasicAuthHeader` is set to `true` (but it doesn't really matter, when it was set to `false` same thing happened). Any idea why that happens and how to fix that?
2. Now let's assume I provided the correct credentials the first time (when everything works), the initial authentication goes fine. Now when I try to fetch the DTO from a service marked with `[Authenticate]` attribute, I get:

   `ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.WebServiceException: Internal Server Error`

With inner exception:

```
  System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
  at ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonTypeSerializer.EatValue (System.String value, System.Int32& i) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonTypeSerializer.EatTypeValue (System.String value, System.Int32& i) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeListWithElements`2[DTO.Report,ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonTypeSerializer].ParseGenericList (System.String value, System.Type createListType, ServiceStack.Text.Common.ParseStringDelegate parseFn) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeList`2+<GetParseFn>c__AnonStoreyB[System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[DTO.Report],ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonTypeSerializer].<>m__37 (System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString (System.String value, System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromStream (System.Type type, System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.AsyncServiceClient.HandleResponseError[IList`1] (System.Exception exception, ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.RequestState`1 requestState) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 }
```

Which, as far as I can tell, means the JSON serializer gives up for unknown reason. The funny thing is, if I disable the authentication, the same piece of code works perfectly fine  - asynchronously fetches a list of DTOs by `POST`ing a search request:

`client.SendAsync<IList<DTO.Report>>(searchRequest, OnSuccess, OnError)`

Questions from the first point still stand: why? How to fix that? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, got it working. There was nothing wrong with ServiceStack itself, now I think that I was blatantly misusing the client functionality. Well, that wasn't a smart move, but maybe someone else will learn from my mistakes.

I guess most of the problems stemmed from using the single instance of the client, instead of using a new instance per request. So there were errors... When I changed the functionality to get a new client per request (a little factory, of sorts), `POST`ing an `Auth` object worked perfectly, and everything else went after - seems everything is working just fine now, both with BasicAuth and CredentialsAuth.

Main point of the story, `using` block is your friend with the client and everything points to the fact that re-using the client instance is a big no-no - at least that's what I can tell right now from the problem and the solution.